# How to memcpy() a struct sockaddr_in

Tags: c, c89

I'm programming a server-client program.
On the server I manage the clients through an array of this data structure:

```
struct Client
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    /*...*/
}; 

struct Client CLIENTS[MAX_CLI];
```

When I receive the first packet from the client through my `UDP` socket

```
struct sockaddr_in addr_cli;

memset(&addr_cli,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
b=recvfrom(SOCK_UDP_FATHER, &pdu, sizeof(pdu), MSG_DONTWAIT,
    (struct sockaddr *)&addr_cli, (socklen_t *)&laddr_cli);
```

I want to copy his address to my struct. So I do:

```
memcpy(&CLIENTS[client].addr,(struct sockaddr*)&addr_cli,
    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

printf("IP client: %s",inet_ntoa(CLIENTS[client].addr.sin_addr);
```

The strange thing is that the first try of communication fails, printing `0.0.0.0`. But the next try that the client does, is successful and everything goes fine. Why that happens?

Comment: The code you show looks ok, so the reason must be elsewhere.

Comment: The cast `(struct sockaddr*)` however is not needed.

Comment: Show the declaration of `addr_cli`.

Comment: Also doing `sizeof CLIENTS[client].addr` instead of `sizeof(struct sockaddr*)` would be less error-prone.

Comment: Can you check if you `addr_cli` is filled as expected by `recvfrom`? Is `laddr_cli` initialised to `sizeof addr_cli`?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka So it was that! I didn't init `laddr_cli`. But I don't understand why that is necessary. Thank you.

Comment: @LiLou_: from `man recvfrom`: ...In this case, `addrlen` is a value-result argument.  Before the call, it should be initialized to the size of the buffer  associated  with  `src_addr`. Upon return, `addrlen` is updated to contain the actual size of the source address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addr_cli` was not filled by the call to `recvfrom`. The last two arguments of `recvfrom` are a little bit tricky. They are

```
struct sockaddr *src_addr,
socklen_t *addrlen
```

If `src_addr` is not NULL, the `recvfrom` expects that `addrlen` points to the length of `src_addr` buffer. (Normally it is the size of  `sockaddr` structure). If the value of `addrlen` is too small, the returned address will be truncated. After the call to `recvfrom` the `addrlen` will be set to the actual address length. Look at [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) for details.

So you need to initialize `laddr_cli` before calling `recvfrom()`:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr_cli;
socklen_t laddr_cli = sizeof(addr_cli); // <--

memset(&addr_cli,0,laddr_cli);    
b=recvfrom(SOCK_UDP_FATHER, &pdu, sizeof(pdu), MSG_DONTWAIT,
    (struct sockaddr *)&addr_cli, &laddr_cli);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just this morning when I tried to copy an address returned from getaddrinfo.  It's probably similar to your problem copying an address returned from recvfrom.

I had a struct addrinfo *rp, and I wanted to copy rp->ai_addr to local storage so I could be sure it would stick around after calling freeaddrinfo.  This worked:

```
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
memcpy(&addr, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
```

In my case I could not declare addr as a sockaddr_in because that would overflow the buffer when I saw an AF_INET6 address.  Using sockaddr_in6 worked, but I am sticking with sockaddr_storage so I can be absolutely protocol neutral in case new address families crop up.

EDIT:  That said, it does seem a bit wasteful to keep an entire struct sockaddr_storage as a field in a client structure.  That thing is 128 bytes.  A struct sockaddr_in6 is only 28 bytes.  How "protocol neutral" do I really need to be?

Probably better to keep a sockaddr_in6 and if I ever see an address length greater than that, just have the program die.  That way if someone comes up with a new family AF_WEIRD that's 37 bytes long, I could adapt to it then without having to burn 128 bytes all time until then.

Not only that, but my server sets hints to AF_INET6 anyway, which allows it to receive either AF_INET or AF_INET6 packets, while presumably dropping any new AF_WEIRD.